# XCTest UI Testing - How to lock the screen?

Tags: xctest, xcode-ui-testing

Related to [XCTest UI Testing - How to close and open an app without relaunch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41951539/xctest-ui-testing-how-to-close-and-open-an-app-without-relaunch) is there any way to lock the screen from a UI test? `XCUIDevice.Button` only has three cases, home, volume up and volume down.

Answer (score 1):

XCUIDevice has a private method for this. Shh, it's kinda secret.

```
XCUIDevice.shared.perform(NSSelectorFromString("pressLockButton"))
```