# Open iOS app in background while switch-on the phone

Tags: ios, swift, launch

One of my client's requirements is to launch an app in the background while switch-on the phone. Is it possible to open an app in the background?
I just want to know!!!

Comment: It is a very weird requirement, but NO! You can only fire Notifications which is the only option for the user to interact with the app after a phone being switched on.

Comment: I think It wouldn't be a good thing. Sound is like a hacking.  You may want to check this question out. There is some answers.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42020010/how-to-open-an-application-from-background-ios   by the way be careful about what you trying to do. Apple may reject your app.

Comment: Launch in the background to do what?  Apps can't run generally in the background; they have to execute in one of the specified background modes (e.g. location) - What is the app supposed to do?