# Xcode - Import the XCUIElement.h into bridging header

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xctest, ios-ui-automation

This post discusses how to reopen an application in `XCTest` using the resolve function: [Possible to bring the app from background to foreground?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35295090/possible-to-bring-the-app-from-background-to-foreground)

It mentions that you need to import the `XCUIElement.h` into the bridging header.   Can someone please give details on what this means and how to accomplish this?

I created the Bridging-Header.h and copied in the XCUIElement.h:

[image]

Added the import to the Bridging file:

[image]

Error:
[image]

[image]

I changed the import statement with the file, but then get all these other errors so I'm not sure if I did that right:

[image]

Comment: Drag and trop https://github.com/facebook/WebDriverAgent/blob/8a251d5c309d98671be36469d6ff64f4598198b8/PrivateHeaders/XCTest/XCUIElement.h into your project and then create a Bridging Header and #import the header in the bridging header.

Comment: hi, thanks for the reply.  How/Where do I create a Bridging Header at in xcode?

Comment: https://bohemianpolymorph.wordpress.com/2014/07/11/manually-adding-a-swift-bridging-header/

Comment: What does the import statement look like?   #import XCUIElement.h ?

Comment: #import "XCUIElement.h"

Comment: I updated the question with screenshots of what I did so far.  I did the steps you mentioned, but it is saying that resolve doesn't exist.  Is there something else I still need to do?

Comment: You're missing quotes before and after XCUIElement.h

Comment: argh! Sorry about that.  Ok i fixed that but now I get a build error.  Do i have to remove those imports from the XCUIElement.h file or something?